# How to check if a list of custom types, contains a subset of values of that type in Kotlin?

Tags: list, kotlin

I have a list of a custom date type:

```
val dates = mutableListOf(
    Date(year = 2020, month = 4, day = 3),
    Date(year = 2021, month = 5, day = 16),
    Date(year = 2020, month = 1, day = 29)
)
```

And a set of "months" I need to ensure are in the list:

```
val months = listOf(1, 4)
```

Is there a way to check if `dates` contains all of the `months` from the list? I feel like there could be a way to do this using the `.containsAll()` function on the initial list, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```kotlin
dates.map { it.month }.containsAll(months)
```